# DC.js Not selected at start

Tags: dc.js

My code is like this.

```
barchart
  .width(250)
  .height(200)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .brushOn(false)
  .colors(["#FFBF00","#FFBF00", "#FFBF00"])
  .xAxisLabel("FEAR")
  .dimension(fearDim)
  .group(fearDimGroup);
```

I have made a bar chart in dc.js.what I want to do is that when I first load the page no bar of bar chart should be selected.Can I do that.Is there any method to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The filter method will work for that purpose.  It will select only the bars that match the input that you supply.

For example, you could try:

```
barchart.filter("");
```

This will filter all non-blank bars.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/9VJHe/